# Linq join values from two lists

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to extract two values from separate lists. I have a list of Order objects and a list of Visitors objects, each contains a full list of objects by date.

I need to access Visitors property from VisitorsList and TotalOrders property from OrdersList. Then i need to devide each TotalOrders with Visitors to get a third value (conversionrate). Finally I want to add each conversionRate value to List TotalConversions.

I'm trying to write a Linq query that takes Visitors and TotalOrders from respective but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
 List<GAVisitorsModel> VisitorsList = GetGAStatisticsReport(model);
        List<GC_OrdersModel> OrdersList = GetOrderReport(model);
        List<GC_ConversionRateModel> TotalConversions = new List<GC_ConversionRateModel>();
        foreach (var order in OrdersList)
        {
            string _date = order.Date;

            var Conversions = VisitorsList.Join(OrdersList, x => x.Visitors, y => y.TotalOrders, (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y });


            foreach (var c in Conversions)
            {

                //-- Y / X = C

                //int _conversion = C;

                //-- GC_ConversionRateModel GC_Orders = new GC_ConversionRateModel(_date, _conversion)
            }
        }    

        return TotalConversions;
```

List TotalConversions should return a list of conversions by date.

These are the object classes:

**GAVisitorsModel:**

```
public class GAVisitorsModel : IGAVisitorsModel
    {

        public string Date { get; set; }
        public int Visitors { get; set; }

        public GAVisitorsModel(string _date, string _visitors)
        {

            Date = _date;
            Visitors = _visitors;

        }

    }
```

**GCOrdersModel:**

```
 public class GC_OrdersModel
    {

        public string Date { get; set; }
        public int TotalOrders { get; set; }
        public int TotalProducts {get; set;}



        public GC_OrdersModel(string _date, int _totalOrders, int _totalProducts)
        {
            Date = _date;
            TotalOrders = _totalOrders;
            TotalProducts = _totalProducts;
        }

    }
```

**GC_ConversionRateModel:**

```
public class GC_ConversionRateModel
{

    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int ConversionRate { get; set; }



    public GC_ConversionRateModel(string _date, int _conversionRate)
    {
        Date = _date;
        ConversionRate = _conversionRate;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is a key that you want to join by?

Comment: I think you need to provide the class structure for each of your objects for us to help you.

Comment: @Anatolii Gabuza well the key would be "OrdersList Date" and the value would be Visitors/TotalOrders. I'm using Google Charts API i need Date and ConversionValue for X and Y axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the below works for you

```
public List<GC_ConversionRateModel> GetConversionRate()
    {

        List<GAVisitorsModel> VisitorsList = GetGAStatisticsReport(model);
        List<GC_OrdersModel> OrdersList = GetOrderReport(model);
        List<GC_ConversionRateModel> TotalConversions = new List<GC_ConversionRateModel>();

        OrdersList.ForEach(o => {
            TotalConversions.Add((from v in VisitorsList
                                 where v.Date == o.Date
                                 select new GC_ConversionRateModel(o.Date, o.TotalOrders / v.Visitors)).FirstOrDefault());

        });

        return TotalConversions;
    }
```

Also, in your `GAVisitorsModel` there seem to be an error when you try to assign string to an integer in `Visitors = _visitors;` in the `ctor`.

Comment: This syntax sure looks smooth and impressive. Will look more into this. It compiles and runs but ConversionRate is 0, i do get Date though. About the string to int iv'e converted all values to proper data types now. Visitors int and TotalOrders int. It should work as it's just int/int but something else must be the propblem. Will investigate this further. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use:

```
var result = from visitor in VisitorsList
             join order in OrdersList on visitor.Date equals order.Date into orders
             select new {
                 Visitor = visitor,
                 VisitorOrders = orders
             };
```

Assuming you have some property that *"connects"* visitor and order (`Date` value) you'll have list of visitors with corresponding orders.

Comment: Ok i see. Well i don't have a Id-property for Visitors. Ive made an Google Analytics API client that fetches number of visitors filtered by date. I only created Date and visitors property to reperesent the corresponding values i get from the API. However both GCOrdersModel and GAVisitorsModel contain a Date property, meaby i could use that as an ID? The end result would be ConversionRate by Date so they both have Date in common.